VSCode Global search hide folder structure
Looks like an update changed my search so now global search orders folders by parent folder structure.  I just want the file names alphabetically, and do not need the tree structure of the files in my global search results.  I have a lot of nested folders and this takes way to much space.  I can't find the setting to revert to the old way.

What is "global search" in this context? The "magnifying glass search icon" in the activity bar or something else?

VS Code allows you to quickly search over all files in the currently opened folder. Press Ctrl+Shift+F and enter your search term.

Ok - you mentioned a "tree structure" - do you perhaps have the view option changed? (this icon:  https://i.sstatic.net/HlqGke0O.png)

There is an icon ion the top right that toggles this feature

